# Creating Left Outer Join Query in Cognos

Tags: sql, left-join, cognos

I have the following problem. In one table I have a list of Clients with ID, in another table, I have a list of Calls for those Clients. In the datamodel I have marked relationship 0 to many. 1 client can have 0 or many calls. When I create my query I add Client Id and Client Name from Client Table and then add count from Calls Table. In the filter section, I have a filter on Client id and filter on Date Range on Calls Table.

This way I only get clients that had calls and clients without calls do not appear on in the results. Using SQL I wrote the same query to test results and here is what I found.

Using this query I get both clients that have calls and do not have calls. `Count(CallId)` returns `0`.

```sql
select ct.clientid
,ct.ClientName
,count(cs.callid)
from client ct
left outer join calls cs
on ct.clientid = cs.clientid
and cs.CallRecievedDateTime > '1/1/2012' 
and cs.CallRecievedDateTime < '1/2/2012'
where ct.clientid in (1,2,5)
group by ct.clientid, ct.ClientName
```

Using this query I only get counts for clients with calls. and clients without calls do not appear in results

```
select ct.clientid
,ct.ClientName
,count(cs.callid)
from client ct
left outer join calls cs
on ct.clientid = cs.clientid
where ct.clientid in (1,2,5)
and cs.CallRecievedDateTime > '1/1/2012' 
and cs.CallRecievedDateTime < '1/2/2012'
group by ct.clientid, ct.ClientName
```

I can figure out a way to simulate this in Cognos. I solved this problem by creating additional Cognos queries just for the client and then joining it to count query and then using results to display. I want to know if there a way to do it in 1 COGNOS query.

Please do not post SQL Queries. The first query listed is what I'm trying to do in Cognos Application.

Here is another way to get the same results as the first query

```sql
SELECT ClientId,
ClientName,
counts
FROM (SELECT clientid,
ClientName
FROM Client
WHERE clientid in (1,2,5) ) cd
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT clientid,
COUNT(*) counts
FROM calls cs
WHERE cs.CallRecievedDateTime > '1/1/2012'
AND cs.CallRecievedDateTime < '1/2/2012'
GROUP BY clientid) b
ON cd.clientid = b.clientid
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only clients that had calls , You have to replace the `left outer join` with `inner join`

Comment: Sorry i must not have been crear. I'm currently only getting clients with calls. I want client with no calls.

Answer (score 0):

You should do :

```
select ct.clientid
,ct.ClientName
,count(cs.callid)
from client ct
left outer join calls cs
on ct.clientid = cs.clientid
where ct.clientid in (1,2,5)
and cs.clientid not in (select ct.clientid from client ct inner join calls cs
on ct.clientid = cs.clientid   and cs.CallRecievedDateTime > '1/1/2012' 
and cs.CallRecievedDateTime < '1/2/2012')
and cs.CallRecievedDateTime > '1/1/2012' 
and cs.CallRecievedDateTime < '1/2/2012'
group by ct.clientid, ct.ClientName
```

Comment: This query does not work, this makes absolutely no sense, you are excluding all clientid from call table?!

Comment: You are right , I edited it. I added inner join to calls table in the sub query. Now the sub query selects only client with calls, and "not in" select what you want - client with no calls

Comment: You are still not going to get any results. you are excluding all client id.

in my first query i get all 3 client ids. 1,2,5 even though 5 does not have calls.
in your query you will not get any rows on return.

Comment: In the sub query I do inner join between client table and calls table. So it select only client with calls - in your data 1,2 . When I select cs.clientid that not in the sub query , It must select clientid 5 .

Comment: Not only it is not going to select 5 it will also exclude 1 and 2. your query will result in 0 rows.

Comment: When you execute only the sub query, Which client id do you get?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7249/discussion-between-twtw-and-sauce)